# How to override addAll function in Java?

Tags: java, list, overriding

For instance I have two Arraylists with different data types.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intValues.add(1);
intValues.add(2);
intValues.add(3);
        
ArrayList<String> strValues = new ArrayList<String>();
strValues.add("4");
strValues.add("5");
strValues.add("6");
```

If both of these lists contained the same data type objects, I would easily call addAll function;

```
intValues.addAll(intValues2);
```

But of course if I try to call addAll function with these different type lists, compiler warns me with **incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Integer>** warning.

So I have to create a bad solution like;

```
for(String s: strValues)
{
   intValues.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, I mean, creating a class which implements List, overriding addAll function etc. so I will be able to call;

```
intValues.addAll(strValues);
```

And intValues list will contain 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Edit: I really don't want to store String values in an Integer array, I have to deal with some creepy old code at the moment and I need a Collection to hold some differend kinds of classes, trying to create a Constructor for those objects, this integer-string scenario is just a simple way to introduce my problem.

Let me tell you about my current situation with another integer-string like scenario:
Creepy class A is car, it holds car's weight, price, color, engine type.
Creepy class B is watch, it holds watch's still type, movement type, price, lug size etc.

I am trying to create a holder class, so it will hold those classes and adding a few functions (for example, overriding compare method makes the holder class to compare prices of different classes).

Now I think I have to create a HolderHolder class which implements List so I can call holderHolder.addAll(carsList) and holderHolder.addAll(watchesList), and it will hold these as Holder objects and yes, this does not look pretty.

Comment: Firstly why would you *want* to store different types in the same `Collection`? Secondly you could make the 'super collection' of type `Object` if for some reason you were forced to do that

Comment: I don't want to store different types in the same collection, edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You act as if what you want is self-evident and logical. It really isn't. `"4"` and `4` are entirely unrelated, and expecting that your list of integers now has a value `4` when you call `addAll` with `"4"` is, as a consequence, as bizarre as expecting your list of movies to gain 'Forrest Gump' when you call `.addAll(colorsOfTheRainbow)` on that, because in your mind, 'green' is so incredibly similar to 'Forrest Gump', that you might as well assume that. (Here, 'green' is `"4"` and 'Forrest Gump' is `4`).

So let's do some work and make this more sensible:

That 'assumption' (that `"4"` is so similar to `4`, that you want `.add("4")` to just mean that 4 shows up in your list) needs to encoded, explicitly, in your code. Now it makes sense, and now you can write a function that maps `Green` to `Forrest Gump` and use it for that example just the same - we've generalized the principle.

What you're really talking about is a **mapping function** that maps an element of your `List<String>` (so.. a `String`) to a type that your target list is of (`Integer`), and you then want the operation: Take this list. Map every value in it with my mapping function. Then, add all the mapped values to this other list.

**That** makes perfect sense.

So, write that.

```
List<Integer> intValues = ...;
strValues.map(Integer::valueOf).forEachOrdered(intValues::add);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bad smell.

One bad Solution can be an own implementation of an List with Type Object. But than you have to cast and work with the Classes of the primitive types.

I think i every case you have to parse or cast. That cost to much of performance just for easy call of addAll.

I would think about the incoming data and why they have to be the same but in different types?

Edit:

If i get to know it correct. It is a little bit hard to understand without more detailed infos.
But maybe you can write an mapper class to map thoose old creepy classes in one new class an then you can put these new class in an collection and can compare all by overriding equals.

```java
public class CreepyClassMapper
{
  public CreepyClassMapper(Car aCar, Watch aWatch)
  {
  }

  @override
  private boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
     // maybe add an instance check
     CreepyClassMapper other = (CreepyClassMapper) object;
     // do your compare stuff
     return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if i were you, i will create a function like this in util class

```
public void append(ArrayList<Integer> intValues, ArrayList<String> strValues){
}
```